# How do I call async methods in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, sorting, lambda

I want to order array by method:

```
MyList.OrderBy(p=>CalcValue(p))
```

I want that the calculation will execute async.

I'm using .net 4 so I can't declare the methods as async.

If I would create some kind of code that first will calculate the values, store them and only than sort it by lambda expression but how can I do it directly inside of the lambda expression?

Is it possible?

Comment: You'll need to explain exactly what you mean by "the calculation will execute async" - what's the context here? What are you trying to return? More details would make it a lot easier to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear from your question what exactly you want.

This may help you, it will first calculate all the values and then will sort it with it, although your term aync is unclear to me for this context.

```
MyList.Select(p=>new {p,CalcValue = CalcValue(p)})
       .OrderBy(x=>x.CalcValue)
       .Select(x=>x.p);
```

Comment: Welcome! Is it what you wanted?

Comment: You can mark it as correct answer if it helped you and it is what you wanted.